# Book suggestion for upsampling and downsampling

Tags: downsampling, books, upsampling

I want to ask for a  good textbook or online material  which explains
in detail:

> -the time and frequency domain mathematics
> behind  upsampling and downsampling.
> -easy to follow

Note: Oppenheim's discrete-time signal processing book is hard to follow.

Comment: hm, could you be more specific about what you need to understand about this? Because, in all honesty, while your question isn't specific enough to preclude you actually need a book about multirate systems and complex polyphase resamplers, it does sound like you're just confused about the basics of aliasing and imaging, as that is really all you need to explain upsampling and downsampling. If that's the case, *any* resource would be hard to follow, because you're missing the basics...

Comment: I tried to learn upsampling and downsampling from  Oppenheim's discrete-time signal processing book but it was hard to follow. As I said,  I  need the time and frequency domain mathematics behind upsampling and downsampling.

Comment: yes, and as I said, the whole math behind that is just "aliasing" and "imaging": make sure you understand these; you're really not being any more specific...

Comment: my question was clear and easy:  any other alternative material for the same basic topics?

Comment: Yes, plenty. Literally *every other book* on discrete-time signal processing will tell you the same about aliasing and imaging  as Oppenheim-Schaefer; it's the standard book for a reason, the math really doesn't change. It's really hard to recommend a single book from a library of choices if you can't even narrow down *what* you found hard to follow, and just insist it was hard.

Comment: The problem really is that we know nothing about where you're coming from: did you get the same basics education as me, and understand well why aliasing happens when going from continuous to discrete time, and only need to be told how to transfer that concept for discrete/discrete sampling? Or do you come from a "discrete first" background? What about your math abilities? What about basics of Fourier analysis in discrete time?

Comment: Switching books in the middle of learning is usually a bad idea: you've read the 180 pages leading up to Oppenheim's chapter on sample rate conversions in discrete time. Now you'll have to read about the same amount of pages to understand the new book's mathematical framework.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is:

Essentials of Digital Signal Processing 1st Edition
by B. P. Lathi

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1107059321/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107059321)

where in Section 6.6 you can find detailed discussions and good examples.

Comment: Lathi is definetely a recommended book. Nevertheless, *sampling* is harder to understand than some other DSP topics, as there's manipulations of functions through their Fourier transforms, and a mixture of continuous & discrete time signals can make it a little bit confusing at first. Try writing your own Octave/Matlab codes for gaining better insight. Or better come gere and ask specific questions, incuding those from Opp book too.

Answer (score 0):

chapter 2 of the following book is in fact the best source:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/9811049610](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9811049610)